# add value into NSArray with looping xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uipickerview

My client does not want date of birth input with three separate UIPickerView thus I may need to create three picker view and input value into it. For Birth Date and Month is no problem as adding like that

```
pickerArray = @[@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", @"7", @"8", @"9", @"10",
                        @"11", @"12", @"13", @"14", @"15", @"16", @"17", @"18", @"19", @"20",
                        @"21", @"22", @"23", @"24", @"25", @"26", @"27", @"28", @"29", @"30", @"31"];
```

But for Birth Year, I don't need to spend my time to manually add year value into UIPickerView. I want to set "start year" and "end year" into loop and add these into UIPickerView. It can be feasible to do?

Comment: Why can't you just use UIDatePicker ?

Comment: @MidhunMP From the question: "My client want date of birth input with three separate UIPickerView". Clients can want what appear to be silly things.

Comment: @MidhunMP my client does not want instead.

Comment: @ppshein With the last change to the question it is self contradictory stating: "client does not want date of birth input with three separate" and then: "thus I may need to create three picker view".

Comment: @ppshein Consider that using your method invalid date combinations can be entered too, like 31 February...

Comment: @Templar Yap, correct. I'll put that burden on backend api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take a mutableArray

```
-(NSMutableArray *)arrayWithYear:(int)startDate andEnddate:(int)endDate {
    NSMutableArray *yearArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i=startDate; i<=endDate; i++) {
       [yearArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",i]];
   }
    return yearArray;
}
```

And just call the function

```
NSArray *myYearArray = [self arrayWithYear:1975 andEnddate:2005]
```